# How do I get rodeo kills?

Tags: titanfall

I'm at Gen 6 so I need to get 50 rodeo kills to move on to the next generation.  However, despite destroying Titan after Titan while rolling the Spitfire LMG with the Slammer upgrade, I'm not getting any credit.

It seems connected to when I doom a Titan, the kill log will say the weapon was **[Spitfire LMG]**, not **[Rodeo]**.  I don't quite get what counts as a "rodeo" kill if not dooming it while rodeo'd (or is that just it; doom ≠ kill?).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, for this particular challenge, dooming the titan isn't enough. You have to rodeo it until it blows up.

For most other challenges, dooming is enough, but that isn't the case here. When you get the titan in its doomed state, keep firing until it explodes. Like you mentioned, it will show your weapon as the cause of death, not just "Rodeo."

Comment: "dooming the titan isn't with."? and "it Erikwill show..."

Comment: Sorry! My phone seems to have picked the wrong word there.

Comment: I'm not too sure about this; do you have a source?

Comment: @peper757 Personal experience. I've completed the Gen 6 challenges, and this is how I did it.